# Dedicated top-bar icon, to easily switch output source (from and to AirPlay)

Tags: macos, airplay

It annoys me that I have to option-click the volume icon in my top-bar, to enable/disable AirPlay. Does anyone know if there's a small application out there, that does the same, without installing additional sound-drivers, and what not..?